# Can we make a round JButton with a round Image as the buttons icon?

Tags: java, swing

I need to make a **JFrame** with a round button and with a round image as the button's Icon(Any thing will but **a mask would be easier for me**).

So far I have searched for these things but I have found a round JButton but with text([Making a round button by Java Examples](http://www.javacodex.com/More-Examples/2/14)) instead of an image. I (**for the masking**) have seen the [Masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423130/how-to-make-circle-image-label-in-java) but don't know how to implement it to the button please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `paintComponent(g)` method of the RoundButton class as followed.

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setClip(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));  // set the area that shall be painted
    g.drawImage(bim, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);    // draw the image, if available
    if (getModel().isArmed()) {      // show a slight gray shading when pressing the button
        g.setColor(new Color(127, 127, 127, 80));   // gray with 80 as alpha
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
    }
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

In addition, define a global variable `private BufferedImage bim` and set it with this method:

```
public void setButtonImage(BufferedImage pbim) {
    bim = pbim;
    repaint();
}
```

This should work fine for your needs. Like this you have a round button with text and an image.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I wrote an [OvalButton](https://github.com/lukakralj/Useful_misc/blob/master/Java/ovalButton/OvalButton.java) class that can handle oval, circular and capsule-like shaped JButtons.

In your case, extend the [OvalButton](https://github.com/lukakralj/Useful_misc/blob/master/Java/ovalButton/OvalButton.java) class and override `getBackgroundImage()` method to return the image you want to set as the background. Then add listeners and text as usually. Only a click on the oval/circular area triggers the action.

Example of a button class for your needs:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageButton extends OvalButton {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImageButton() {
        super(); // Default is oval/circle shape.

        setBorderThickness(0); // Oval buttons have some border by default.

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("your_image.jpg")); // Replace with the path to your image.
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            image = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected BufferedImage getBackgroundImage() {
        return image;
    }
}
```